# Can we rank markov matrices in stochastic order?

Tags: markov-process, stochastic-ordering

I am familiar with the concept of [stochastic ordering](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_ordering) for two random variables and how we can say if a markov matrix is stochastically monotone. What im interested in is if there is a concept for ranking two separate markov matrices.

To illustrate suppose we have two stochastically monotone Markov matricies $A$ and $B$ which preserve the ordering of $x\succsim y$. Under what circumstances can we say (if any) that matrix $A$ is preferred to matrix $B$ in stochastic order?

*Note: The definitions im using are from this slide deck:* http://polaris.imag.fr/jean-marc.vincent/index.html/Slides/asmta09.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A$ and $B$ are two Markov kernels. One example where a "matrix $A$ is preferred to matrix $B$" is when, under certain conditions,
$$
A(x,C) \ge B(x,C)
$$
for any $x,C$ such that $x \not\in C$. This is a *Peskun ordering*, written as $A \succeq_P B$. I think of this intuitively as "$A$ just moves around more than $B$."

If these transition kernels correspond to MCMC samplers, and if you're able to show that $A \succeq_P B$, then $A$ is a superior algorithm in the sense that it gives you estimators with smaller asymptotic variance, among other things.

- https://www.jstor.org/stable/2335011
- https://projecteuclid.org/journals/annals-of-applied-probability/volume-8/issue-1/A-note-on-Metropolis-Hastings-kernels-for-general-state-spaces/10.1214/aoap/1027961031.full
- https://arxiv.org/pdf/1906.06197.pdf

Comment: Thanks for introdoucing me to this concept! I actually found that this source here provides a much more introductory overview:

https://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.46.3606&rep=rep1&type=pdf  Definition 3.2 is most informative